# Yum unable to resolve dependency of a existing file in the $PATH

Tags: linux

I am trying to install a rpm and it is failing due to a unresolved dependance. The file libc.so.6 is the the path of $PATH, so don't know what it is complaining about.

```
# yum install libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64.rpm                      Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with ULN.
ULN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Examining libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64.rpm: libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64
Marking libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libdb.x86_64 0:5.3.21-3.fc18 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: libdb

--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) for package: libdb
--> Processing Conflict: libdb conflicts filesystem < 3
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 from /libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> libdb conflicts with filesystem
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 from /libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by package libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 (/libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64)
libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 from /libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by package libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 (/libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64)
Error: libdb conflicts with filesystem
Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by package libdb-

5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 (/libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64)
Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by package libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64 (/libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.


[root@db1 php]# locate libc.so.6
/lib/libc.so.6
/lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
/lib64/libc.so.6
/u01/oracle/112/lib/stubs/libc.so.6

 echo $PATH
/lib64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:    /usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/lib64/:/usr/lib:/u01/oracle/112/lib:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/apr/lib:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/apr/lib:/usr/local/src:/usr/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a CentOS system you're installing this Fedora RPM on? Fedora RPMs are built against newer versions of middleware and libraries than CentOS in most cases.

On a CentOS 6 machine of mine:

```
$ rpm -qp --conflicts /tmp/libdb-5.3.21-3.fc18.x86_64.rpm
filesystem < 3

$ rpm -qa | grep filesystem
filesystem-2.4.30-3.el6.x86_64
```

I found the spec file and there is an explicit conflict for the package `filesystem` on versions less than 3.0.

Also, that RPM has a requirement of GLIBC higher than what you are probably running.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

RPM, which yum uses, doesn't look at the filesystem. It looks at the rpmdb. The same rpmdb that doesn't contain that dependency.

Comment: Install the package that provides it.

Comment: I don't know which package provides it. How do you find which package provides it?

Comment: You ask yum. But you won't find it; UL doesn't provide it.

Comment: can't you provide a straight answer?

Comment: Okay, here's your straight answer: **DON'T INSTALL FEDORA PACAKGES ON EL.**